# Word that expresses feeling of safety, security, and being able to relax finally

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to find a word to represent feeling happy (but in a more content and satisfied way rather than elated) combined with a sense of security and stability in one's life.

E.g.

> After many ups and downs, she finally found a steady job and settled into a comfortable long-term rental. Years of anxiety and stress had taken its toll, but she could now relax and feel _______. Things had worked out in the end.

The best I could come up with was *content*, but it feels a bit dry and doesn't really capture the depth of feeling.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **halcyon** or **halcyonic**.

It conveys a sense of security through its definition of prosperity and tranquility. If one is calm, tranquil, happy and prosperous at once, then one is also likely feeling safe and secure.
Halcyon is also a seldom used word, which may cause the reader pay close attention to the specific word rather than just the overall more generic "happy" feeling.

Source for usage of word: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=halcyon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalcyon%3B%2Cc0

1.
calm; peaceful; tranquil:

```
halcyon weather.
```

2.
rich; wealthy; prosperous:

```
halcyon times of peace.
```

3.
happy; joyful; carefree:

```
halcyon days of youth.
```

Source: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/halcyon

Comment: Cite the source where you got this definition.

Comment: I think "halycon" does capture that sense of security and tranquility, however I am not sure I would apply it to someones feelings in the present.

Comment: True, maybe "halcyonic" then.

Answer (score 1):

quiet, powerful and omnipotent:  consider **serene**

1 a : clear and free of storms or unpleasant change

```
serene skies
```

b : shining bright and steady

```
the moon, serene in glory —Alexander Pope
```

2 : august —used as part of a title

```
His Serene Highness
```

3 : marked by or suggestive of utter calm and unruffled repose or quietude

```
a serene smile
```

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serene

Comment: You need to cite your source.

Comment: Answers should consist mostly of your own words. If all you are going to do is copy some reference work, the question should be closed [under this guidance](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) from Stack Exchange management.

Comment: *Serenity now!!!*

Answer (score 0):

Consider *Feeling at peace*.

Oxford dictionary:

> Free from anxiety or distress.

*Peaceful* would also work, meaning *"Free from disturbance; tranquil."* but when applied to a person one may be inclined to read it in its other meaning, *"2.1 (of a person) inclined to avoid conflict."*